# How to execute a query from the result of another query

Tags: grails

It works:

```
def c = DomainClass.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    ge("property1", params.param1.toInteger())
    le("property2", params.param2.toFloat())
}
```

We want to add one more condition:

**Attempt 1) Previous to createCriteria:**

```
def preResults = DomainClass.getAllByProperty3GreaterThan(0)
def c = preResults.createCriteria()
...
```

It gives the error: *No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.createCriteria() is applicable for argument types: () values: []*

**Attempt 2) After createCriteria:**

```
...
postResults = results.getAllByProperty3GreaterThan(0)
```

It gives the error: *No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.getAllByProperty3GreaterThan() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [0]*

The reason to do not include everything inside createCriteria is that preResults (or postResults) are the result of a function of a Service... I omitted the Service here (and changed the name of the variables) to simplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot chain `findBy` finders (or criteria) like that... the first finder is called on a domain class (and that is fine because the finders are methods of the domain class), but it returns a `PersistentSet` which does not have `findBy` methods on it.

There are 2 things (I can think of) you can attempt:

- Use `criteria` first and then `results.findAll { it.property3 }` but that fetches all the results into the memory and does filtering there
- Create a named query (you can chain those and put a `findBy` at the end)... something like this `DomainClass.myNamedQuery.findAllByProperty3GreaterThan(0)`. The named query should do what the `criteria` in your question does. See more about the named queries [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html).

Comment: I don't understand the first idea, @zoran119. Could you give me an example, please? The second idea should work (if I'm able to pass the named query from the Controller to the Service), but it doesn't look made for this purpose... :/

Comment: You don't need to pass the named query from the controller to the service. You just declare the named query in the domain class (as per the documentation I linked) and simply use it in the service like this: `DomainClass.myNamedQuery.findAllByProperty3GreaterThan(0)`.

Comment: The first idea would be something like this... first do `def c = DomainClass.createCriteria()`, then `def results = c.list { /*stuff*/ }` and then finally `def filteredResults = results.findAll { it.property3 }`. Note that `it.property3` will return `true` if its value is greater than zero (just a shorthand way of writing `it.property3 > 0`)

Comment: The first idea worked perfectly. Thank you! I'm wondering if it is better to keep the controller tiny or move the logic from the service to it (better performance for sure!)...

Comment: I don't think you'd get any performance benefit by moving your code from the controller to a service... if anything there will be a negligible penalty invoking the service layer. You'd move the logic to  a service for reusability, readability and so on.

Comment: I mean, if I use the Service there is a performance penalty as I will have to use `results.findAll { it.property3 }` instead of get all the data from a single Criteria. In any case, thank you for all your explanations! :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue in doing like below, even if your service method does the same thing wrt `property3`?

```
def results = c.list {
    ge("property1", params.param1.toInteger())
    le("property2", params.param2.toFloat())
    gt("property3", 0)
}
```

Do you have extra logic present in the service method other that the trivial one liner, which cannot be represented in the criteria above?

`DomainClass.getAllByProperty3GreaterThan(0)`

I am just curious to know the rationale behind sticking to the service method.

Comment: It could be represented with a single criteria, but the Controller would grow up a lot, and the code would become less clear. The call of the service would be something like: `postResults = AdvancedFilterService.function(results, params.param3)` Do you want that I copy&paste the real code of the service here? (which doesn't work yet)